# Is it possible to utilize Pydio's v1 or v2 API with Pydio Cells?

Tags: rest, api, pydio

I'm currently using the the Pydio demo to test out the capabilities of the Pydio Cells API. https://demo.pydio.com/

I am successfully able receive valid JSON responses using a Bearer token when making calls to the Pydio Cells API.

> https://[yourPydioServer.com]/a/

```
https://demo.pydio.com/a/config/discovery/
```

I've attempted many variations of the below in attempts to utilize v1 or v2 APIs without any success.

> https://[yourPydioServer.com]/pydio/api/v2/

```
https://demo.pydio.com/pydio/api/v2/fs
https://demo.pydio.com/pydio/api/2/fs
https://demo.pydio.com/pydio/a/2/fs
https://demo.pydio.com/a/2/fs
https://demo.pydio.com/a/v2/fs
```

So far I'm unable to figure out or find any documentation stating that the v1 or v2 APIs are able to be used or not.  No mention I can find anywhere.

**Some links to Pydio documentation active as of 02.13.19**

> API Version 2: https://pydio.com/en/pydio-api-v2
>   API Version 1: https://pydio.com/en/pydio-api-v1

**The Only documentation I'm able to locate regarding REST API related to Pydio Cells is below.**

> https://pydio.com/en/docs/cells/v1/using-rest-api
>
> https://pydio.com/en/docs/developer-guide/protocol
>
> https://pydio.com/en/docs/developer-guide/producing-jwt-using-postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this to be NO.  Pydio Cells API is not compatible with previous versions of Pydio.